# Value is coming from database in textarea in single line

Tags: java, jsp

I have a textarea in my jsp page. I am submitting the data to database as it is getting updated line by line into database. When i am retriveing the value from database in textarea and showing to the user then it is coming in one line even i have inserted data in different line. Can any one suggest any answer.

Code:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(QueryHelper.setQuestion); 
preparedStatement.setString(1, strvideoqueId); 
preparedStatement.setString(2, que); 
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, Convert.toSqlTimeStamp(today));
```

where que is the question which is coming from textarea.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Can you share the code-part used to insert data to DB?

Comment: where que is the question which is coming from textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` between each line before adding the text in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The textarea tag in HTML provides the attribute `wrap`. Add it and using the value `physical`. So if the user pressed the return or enter key, the browser submits the line breaks too.

Comment: I have given the phusical value of wrap but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using  tag.